# How can I prevent web.config being overwritten during web deployment of ASP.NET Core 2.0 app?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

When I deploy an ASP.NET 2.0 app from Visual Studio using web deploy, in automatically generates a web.config on the server overwriting the any existing web.config on the server. I want to set different value for various environment variables (such as ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT for example) in different applications. I don't want the web config to be part of the project as the values for the environment variables will different for different servers so I want to set up different config files on each server.

Comment: I suggest you to use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms

Comment: This is interesting but I don't want the various settings for different environments included in my checked in source code, as it includes secrets such as connection strings - I want to keep these on the server to which they belong.

Comment: What about doing this in you build pipline. For example use https://cakebuild.net/